# (C++) Writing and reading a dynamic array to a binary file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, binary

I'm new here so forgive me if I make some mistakes.
Anyway, I've got this code here:

```
class List{
    private:
        int dim;
        Reservations *res; //Dynamic array of reservations that composes "List"
    public:
        List();
        List(int dm, Reservations *resv);
        ~List();
        int getDim();
        void setDim(int dm);
        void readNwrite(List &ls);
};
```

This is a class and I need to write and read the Reservations array in a binary file. The Reservations class is composed of other types of data (two strings, an integer and also another class).
Here you can see the Reservations class:

```
class Reservations{
    private:
        DateTime dt;
        string name, phone;
        int codVisit;
    public:
        Reservations();
        Reservations(DateTime datT, string nm, string tel, int cod);
        ~Reservations();
        DateTime getDt();
        void setDt(DateTime datT);
        string getName();
        void setName(string nm);
        string getTel();
        void setTel(string tel);
        int getCodVisit();
        void setCodVisit(int cod);
        void read();
        void print();
};
```

And here's the class DateTime:

```
class DateTime{
    private:
        Date d;
        int sec, min, hrs;
    public:
        DateTime();
        DateTime(int s, int m, int o, int d, int ms, int y);
        ~DateTime();
        void getDt();
        void setDt(int g, int ms, int y);
        int getSec();
        void setSec(int s);
        int getMin();
        void getMin(int m);
        int getOre();
        void getOre(int o);
        void print();
        void read();
        int validate();
        int compare(DateTime dt1);
    friend void Anglform(DateTime dt);
};
```

This is how I've done created and read the binary file in the List class:

```
void List::readNwrite(List &ls){
    ofstream file("list.dat", ios::binary);
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(res), sizeof(Reservations) * dim);
    file.close();

    ifstream fileF("list.dat", ios::binary);
    ls.setDim(dim);
    ls.res = new Reservations[ls.dim];
    fileF.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ls.res), sizeof(Reservations) * dim);
    file.close();
}
```

I've tried it but it isn't working. I know that the second instance is getting the contents of the first one, but in the end the program always crashes...

Comment: Heads up : using reinterpret_cast to cast a sequence of bytes to an object (Reservations) will not result in a valid object since new will not have been called. You will need to find another way to read your object, e.g. construct your object from the read data.

Comment: "composed of other types of data (two strings, an integer and also another class)" you need to show all that - because your problem could be that you're using things which aren't compatible with reinterpreting the object as a series of bytes.

Comment: A function that writes to file and then reads from it immediately does not make much sense.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I've updated the post with what I use in the Reservations class. Anyway, I know that a method that does both things doesn't make sense, but I did that just for convenience...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to read/write a structure to/from a file as a binary blob, that structure must be [standard layout type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) (aka POD) and not contain any pointers within. Your structure obviously does not satisfy that requirement (`std::string` object is not a standard layout type and does contain a pointer(s) inside) so you have to write reading/writing methods to load/store data member by member or use a library designed for that purpose.

Note: your class `Reservations` violates [the rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)
and you have memory leak right there on this line:

```
ls.res = new Reservations[ls.dim];
```

You better use `std::vector` for dynamic array or if you cannot at least a smart pointer.

Comment: Could I just replace the string object with an array of characters? Would that fix the problem?

Comment: @Fragoloz I do not see the definition of `Date` but if that is standard layout type then yes changing your strings to char array will make it possible to load/store them as binary blobs.

Comment: In the Date class I just have three integer variables so I should be ok with that, right?

Comment: @Fragoloz if it satisfy standard layour type (no virtual methods, same access control etc) then yes.